# Verification of the following integral $\int e^{-x}\arctan e^x\ dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

> Evaluate: 
>   $$
> \int e^{-x}\arctan e^x\ dx
> $$

I'm trying to detect the error with signs in the following calculation without any success for a while already. I've started by substitution:
$$
t= e^{-x}\\
dt = -e^{-x}\ dx \\
dx = -{dt\over e^{-x}}
$$

Then the integral becomes:
$$
-\int \arctan{1\over t}\ dt
$$

Integrating by parts yields:
$$
u = \arctan {1\over t}\\
du = {1\over {1 + {1\over t^2}}}\cdot -{1\over t^2} = -{1\over t^2+1}\ dt\\
dv = dt\\
v = t
$$
Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
I &= -\left(uv - \int v\ du\right) \\
&= -\left(t\arctan{1\over t} - \int -{t\over t^2 + 1}\ dt\right)\\
&=-t\arctan{1\over t}+\int-{t\over t^2 + 1}\ dt\\
&=-t\arctan{1\over t}-\int{t\over t^2 + 1}\ dt\\
&=-e^{-x}\arctan{e^x}-{1\over 2}\ln(t^2 + 1) + C\\
&=-e^{-x}\arctan{e^x}-{1\over 2}\ln(e^{-2x} + 1) + C\\
&=-e^{-x}\arctan{e^x}-{1\over 2}\ln\left({e^{2x} + 1\over e^{2x}}\right) + C\\
&= \boxed{-e^{-x}\arctan{e^x}-{1\over 2}\ln\left({e^{2x} + 1}\right) + x+C}
\end{align}
$$

For some reason, the answer section suggests that :
$$
I = -e^{-x}\arctan e^x + {1\over 2}\ln(1+e^{2x}) -x  + C
$$

Have I missed something? I believe there might be a typo in the book (I've already encountered several ones before), but to be sure I need a verification.

Thank you!

Comment: Mathematica agrees with you and not the book: $$x-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(e^{2 x}+1\right)-e^{-x} \tan ^{-1}\left(e^x\right) $$

Comment: Differenciate both functions to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$t=e^{-x} \implies t>0$.

For $t \in (0,+\infty)$, we have

$$\arctan(\frac 1t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(t)$$

thus

$$\int \arctan(\frac 1t)dt =\frac{\pi}{2}t-\int \arctan(t)dt$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}t-t\arctan(t)+\frac 12\ln(t^2+1)+C$$

$$=t\arctan(\frac 1t)+\frac 12\ln(t^2+1)+C$$
The result is then

$$-e^{-x}\arctan(e^{x})-\frac 12\ln(e^{-2x}+1)+C$$

Your answer is correct since

$$\ln(e^{2x}+1)=\ln(e^{2x}(e^{-2x}+1))$$

$$2x+\ln(e^{-2x}+1)$$